pgfplots filled contour with precomputed contour line coordinates
I'm using contour prepared to generate the contour plot as suggested by the manual (shown below).
I would like to know the way to plot the filled contour with the precomputed contour line coordinates. I've tried with contour filled, surf, etc, but none of them works.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[contour prepared]
        table {
             2  2  0.8        
                              
             0.857143  2  0.6 
             1  1  0.6        
             2  0.857143  0.6 
             2.5  1  0.6      
             2.66667  2  0.6  
                              
             0.571429  2  0.4 
             0.666667  1  0.4 
             1  0.666667  0.4 
             2  0.571429  0.4 
             3  0.8  0.4      
                              
             0.285714  2  0.2 
             0.333333  1  0.2 
             1  0.333333  0.2 
             2  0.285714  0.2 
             3  0.4  0.2      
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

This is the contour plot generated with python.

Here is the plot generated pgfplot with contour prepared with contour line coordinates extracted from the python plot.

Is there a way that I can fill the areas between the contour lines just like the python plot?

contour filled creates filled contours on a surface. Your data is not a surface, but data for a set of lines(contours). It is not possible to create a surface(surf) from this data - the information is simply not there. What is your actual goal?

@hpekristiansen I've edited my question.

Here is a rather manual solution:
\begin{filecontents*}{contours.dat}
0.857143  2  0.6 
 1  1  0.6        
 2  0.857143  0.6 
 2.5  1  0.6      
 2.66667  2  0.6  
                  
 0.571429  2  0.4 
 0.666667  1  0.4 
 1  0.666667  0.4 
 2  0.571429  0.4 
 3  0.8  0.4      
                  
 0.285714  2  0.2 
 0.333333  1  0.2 
 1  0.333333  0.2 
 2  0.285714  0.2 
 3  0.4  0.2      
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colormap/viridis]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0.2,0.4,0.6}{
\addplot[color of colormap={1000*#1}, fill=.,] table[x expr={\thisrowno{2}==#1?\thisrowno{0}:nan}] {contours.dat} --cycle;
}
\addplot[contour prepared, point meta min=0, point meta max=1] table {contours.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


